# Not sure what I'm doing wrong with this recurrence problem

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

$r_{n} = 4r_{n-1} + 6r_{n-2} $

Using Generating Functions I have:

We have $ R(x)= \sum^{\infty}_{i=0}r_nx_n $ $R(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} r_nx_n $. Then we multiply the relation on both sides by $x_nx_n$. After I subbed in R(x)R(x) and subtracted the missing initial values ($r_0=1 $ $r_1=3$ $r_0=1 $ $r_1=3$) and did some algebra.[Full Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWbjV.jpg)

$R(x)[1 - 4x - 6x^2] = 1-x$

Solution Manual Says:

$R(x)[1 - x - 6x^2] = 1-x$

Comment: You will get a better response to your question if you type it directly using LaTeX.  Links tend to do poorly.

Comment: Thank You! I didn't realize LaTeX was so simple haha

Comment: Perhaps you could show how you reached this using generating functions....

Comment: My apologies. We have $R(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} r_{n}x^n$. Then we multiply the relation on both sides by $x^n$. After I subbed in $R(x)$ and subtracted the missing initial values ($r_{0} = 1 r_{1}=3$) and did some algebra.

Comment: Without more details  nobody can say something about your calculations.

Comment: @OmarWali Could you add your comment to the main question by editing the question? Also, did you mean you multiplied both sides by x^2 and not x^n?

Comment: I posted an image of my work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align*} R(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty r_n x^n \\ &= r_0 + r_1 x + \sum_{n=2}^\infty r_n x^n \\ &= r_0 + r_1 x + \sum_{n=2}^\infty 4r_{n-1} x^{n-1} x + 6r_{n-2} x^{n-2} x^2 \\ &= r_0 + r_1 x + 4x \sum_{n=1}^\infty r_n x^n + 6x^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty r_n x^n \\ &= r_0 + r_1 x + 4x (R(x) - r_0) + 6x^2 R(x) \\ &= (6x^2 + 4x)R(x) + r_0 + (r_1 - 4r_0)x.\end{align*}$$  Therefore, $$R(x) = \frac{r_0 + (r_1 - 4r_0)x}{1 - 4x - 6x^2} = \frac{1-x}{1 - 4x - 6x^2}.$$  Your calculation is correct.

To see for certain that the book's answer is not correct, we can observe that the denominator $1-x-6x^2$ factors as $(1+2x)(1-3x)$, and therefore $$\frac{1-x}{1-x-6x^2} = \frac{3}{5}\cdot \frac{1}{1+2x} + \frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{1-3x}.$$  Then by computing the geometric series expansions, we find $$\frac{1-x}{1-x-6x^2} = \frac{1}{5} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( 3(-2)^n + 2(3^n) \right) x^n,$$ which would suggest that $$r_n = \frac{3(-2)^n + 2(3^n)}{5},$$ but this yields $$\{r_n\}_{n=0}^5 = \{1, 0, 6, 6, 42\},$$ which is obviously wrong:  it should be $$\{r_n\}_{n=0}^5 = \{1, 3, 18, 90, 468\}.$$  I leave it to you to verify that your calculation is correct, using a similar method of finding the explicit formula from $R(x)$.

Comment: Thank you, I was very confident in my answer but the textbook we use was written by a professor here and it's still in the preliminary edition so mistakes are plentiful.